# Matplotlib(pyplot) 'str' object is not callable when trying to change y-label

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I try to change y-label in pyplot I get an error.
`'str' object is not callable`
It is strange as I am able to change the x-label without an issue.

I am confused as renaming the xlabel works, but y doesn't.

```
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.hist(asia2007["gdpPerCapita"],20)
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.hist(europe2007["gdpPerCapita"],20)
plt.xlabel("Europe")
plt.ylabel("Freq")
plt.show()
```

I expect a graph with renamed Y label, but it throws an error.

```
----> 6 plt.ylabel("freq")

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: You have probably done `plt.ylabel = "something"` somewhere in your code. Remove it and try again (restart your kernel if using jupyter)

Comment: Can you post more (complete) code which reproduces the problem if it persists even after DavidG's suggestion?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33925268/5851928

Comment: @DavidG I did not have 'plt.ylabel="whatever"' anywhere, but restarting kernal has worked, thanks very much!