# Unable to label axis in juyter TypeError

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

This is the code which I have use to plot except i have removed the key.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas import DataFrame
from alpha_vantage.foreignexchange import ForeignExchange

cc = ForeignExchange(key='  ',output_format='pandas')
data, meta_data = cc.get_currency_exchange_daily(from_symbol='USD',to_symbol='EUR', outputsize='full')
print(data)
data['4. close'].plot()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.title('Intraday USD/Eur')
```

[image]

if i insert `ylabel('label')` i got the following error `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` 
This problem was outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24120023/strange-error-with-matplotlib-axes-labels/33925268#33925268) thus if i restart my juyter kernel the ylabel will show up once but if I rerun the same code i will get the same error again. Is there a bug or is there a problem on my end?

---

I am not sure if it is relevent but the dataframe looks like this

```
Open    High    Low Close
date                
2019-11-15  0.9072  0.9076  0.9041  0.9043
2019-11-14  0.9081  0.9097  0.9065  0.9070
2019-11-13  0.9079  0.9092  0.9071  0.9082
2019-11-12  0.9062  0.9085  0.9056  0.9079
2019-11-11  0.9071  0.9074  0.9052  0.9062
... ... ... ... ...
2014-11-28  0.8023  0.8044  0.8004  0.8028
2014-11-27  0.7993  0.8024  0.7983  0.8022
2014-11-26  0.8014  0.8034  0.7980  0.7993
2014-11-25  0.8037  0.8059  0.8007  0.8014
2014-11-24  0.8081  0.8085  0.8032  0.8036
1570 rows × 4 columns
```

Comment: It's definitely a problem on your code. Make sure there is no assignment to a matplotlib method name present anymore.

Comment: I have updated to show my full code. The only assignment is on this code

Comment: It is working now after i removed from `pandas import DataFrame` but this raises more question. Why?

Comment: One would need to see the full Error for that.