# Keep getting this 'TypeError: 'str' object is not callable' for trying to plot a scatter plot

Tags: python-3.x

Keep getting this error 'TypeError: 'str' object is not callable' by running this code

```py
plt.scatter(cdf.FUELCONSUMPTION_COMB, cdf.CO2EMISSIONS,  color='blue')
plt.xlabel("FUELCONSUMPTION_COMB")
plt.ylabel("Emission")
plt.show()
```

Comment: It was working properly at first but after a few runs it kept giving me this error :-|

Comment: can you write which line giving the error exactly?

Comment: Line 2: plt.xlabel...

Comment: share your full error.

Comment: [is this answer you are looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24120023/strange-error-with-matplotlib-axes-labels)

Comment: yes exactly, thank you, I re-started the kernal and this solved the problem

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33925268/14510802