# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I encountered with this error: `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` when trying to add a label on Y axis for my bar chart. Why? please help. Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
# TODO: Plot company with the most stock and the lowest stock
data = pd.read_csv("c:\\users\\HP\\Downloads\\Stock.csv")

plt.bar(1,data['Stock'].max(), label=data['Company'].max())
plt.bar(1,data['Stock'].min(), label=data['Company'].min())
plt.ylabel("Stock")
plt.legend()
```

Full error:

```
 TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-136cc5c2aaf2> in <module>
      5 plt.bar(1,data['Stock'].max(), label=data['Company'].max())
      6 plt.bar(1,data['Stock'].min(), label=data['Company'].min())
----> 7 plt.ylabel("Stock")
      8 plt.legend()

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strange error with matplotlib axes labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24120023/strange-error-with-matplotlib-axes-labels)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try restarting the Kernel. This sometimes help

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you attached the full code, a simple kernel restart and re-importing libraries should solve it.